# How can I trap deep errors in excel files using Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

This is a particularly gnarly problem for me... I am reading a couple of hundred excel workbooks from a SharePoint list, and each workbook has 30+ worksheets... so heaps of data.

Now in this entire datasource, there are a couple of sheets that have a specific type of error. The excel formula in the worksheet has a problem. It evaluates to a #REF! or maybe a circular loop o the formula showing a #NAME error, or something like this.

Normally, Power Query is pretty good being able to show that I have 10 errors, and then give me options to drill down into those errors.

But in this scenario, it seems that the data cannot even be loaded from the worksheets. So in the Transform screen, where I preview the data, it looks fine, but when I "close and load" I get a pop up saying [DataFormat.Error] Invalid cell value '#REF!'

It's almost as if  PowerQuery is saying "don't even ask about the data - I ran into problems loading it"

**So my question... how do I do error trapping at the load, because all the error handling options I see seem to be after the load, and only in the transformation steps.**

In other words, if I could load the cell value as type text with value #REF then I could deal with it.

I have also tried another approach, that being to switch on the data quality view, on the entire dataset. It says there are 0 errors in all the columns. As in 100% no errors. There are a small percentage of blanks but absolutely no errors at all. So that's obviously wrong too.

**EDIT 1**

Here's my code

```
let
Source = SharePoint.Files("https://............sharepoint.com/sites/.......", [ApiVersion = 15]),
#"Filtered Excel only" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each (Text.Contains([Extension],".xls"))),
#"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Excel only",{{"Name", Text.Lower, type text}}),
#"Filtered planner only" = Table.SelectRows(#"Lowercased Text", each Text.Contains([Name], "planner")),
#"Reduce columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered planner only",{"Name", "Date modified", "Folder Path"}),
#"Added SourceFile" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reduce columns", "SourceFile", each [Folder Path]&[Name]),
#"Extract filename" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added SourceFile", {{"Name", each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_, ".xls"), type text}}),
#"Replaced underscore" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Extract filename","_"," ",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Name"}),

#"Part 1 filewords" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced underscore", "AllFilenameWords", each Text.Split([Name], " ")),
#"Part 2 MonthNameFound" = Table.AddColumn(#"Part 1 filewords", "MonthNameFound", each List.First( List.Intersect( { [AllFilenameWords], #"MonthNames"[MonthName] } ) )),
#"Part 3 YearFound" = Table.AddColumn(#"Part 2 MonthNameFound", "YearFound", each List.First( List.Intersect( { [AllFilenameWords], #"YearsOfInterest"[YearOfInterest] } ) )),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Part 3 YearFound", each ([MonthNameFound] <> null) and ([YearFound] <> null)),
#"Added Period" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Period", each Date.EndOfMonth(Date.FromText("1 " & [MonthNameFound] & " " & [YearFound])), type date),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Added Period",{{"Period", Order.Ascending}, {"SourceFile", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "Name", "Period", "Folder Path", "SourceFile", "AllFilenameWords", "MonthNameFound", "YearFound", "Date modified"}),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns1",{"Folder Path", "AllFilenameWords", "MonthNameFound", "YearFound"}),
#"Part 4 SheetNames" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "SheetName", each 
    let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents([SourceFile]), null, true),
        #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Kind] = "Sheet")),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Data", "Item", "Kind", "Hidden"}),
        #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each (Text.Contains([Name],"-"))),
        NamedSheets = Table.ToList(#"Filtered Rows")
    in
        #"NamedSheets"  
    ),

#"Expanded SheetNames" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Part 4 SheetNames", "SheetName"),
#"Filtered DateRange" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded SheetNames", each [Period] > #date(2023, 2, 1)),
#"Added RosterActuals" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered DateRange", "RosterActuals", each 
    let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents([SourceFile]), null, true),
        #"ThaSheet" = Source{[Item=[SheetName],Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"ErrorsFound" = Table.SelectRowsWithErrors(#"ThaSheet"),
        #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"ThaSheet",{"Column1", "Column2", "Column4"}),
        #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Column2", type text}}),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Column1", "DateOf"}, {"Column2", "OfficerID"}, {"Column4", "RosterArea"}}),
        #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each ([OfficerID] <> null)),
        #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Role", each if Text.StartsWith([OfficerID],"S") then "Supervisor" else "Officer"),
        #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Added Conditional Column","*","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"OfficerID"}),
        #"Changed Type OfficerID" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"OfficerID", Int64.Type},{"DateOf", Date.Type}}),
        #"Replaced Errors with 0" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type OfficerID", {{"OfficerID", 0}}),
        #"Filtered out 0" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Errors with 0", each ([OfficerID] <> 0))
    in
        #"Filtered out 0"
        
    ),
#"Expanded RosterActuals" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added RosterActuals", "RosterActuals", {"DateOf", "OfficerID", "RosterArea", "Role"}, {"DateOf", "OfficerID", "RosterArea", "Role"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded RosterActuals",{{"Name", type text}, {"SourceFile", type text}, {"SheetName", type text}, {"Role", type text}, {"RosterArea", type text}, {"OfficerID", Int64.Type}, {"DateOf", type date}, {"Period", type date}, {"Date modified", type date}}),

in
#"Changed Type"
```

**EDIT 2 - trying to catch an error**

replace the end of the code

```
....
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded RosterActuals",{"Index", "Name", "Period", "SourceFile", "Date modified", "SheetName", "DateOf", "OfficerID", "Role"}),
#"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"RosterArea", Order.Ascending}}),
FinalTable = 
    try #"Sorted Rows1"
    catch (e) => "Sorted Rows1"


in
FinalTable
```

The error message is this:

[image]

If I put a thousand filters into the last step, and I can see this... the error is there. But try sort the column? Bombs out:

[image]

**EDIT 3**

I've run into the same problem again on a different job, and after some thought I think I've found a possible cause of my problem.

There is, I believe, a difference between just loading the data from source, versus loading the table as an AddColumn.

```
this works - error is trappable
= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(".....\workbook.xlsx"), null, true)

this doesn't work - cannot trap the error
= #"AddedSheets" = Table.AddColumn(AddedWorkBookSource, "WorkBookSheets", each Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents([WorkBook]), null, true)),
```

Comment: Please post sample data that demonstrates your problem. Cannot reproduce from the information you provide. Are you certain the file causing the problem is an Excel file?

Comment: Absolutely certain the source files are excel - I have no reason to doubt it at all,. Now I'm trying again on a different data set and I get the same problem. So when I have 300 workbooks and I get this error, there's no way for me to find which workbook is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interests of closing out the discussion, and hopefully achieving a resolution, I've added my own answer here.

One approach was to abandon this approach, and instead extract the data using python. As it was only 10 workbooks, I could just download them to a local folder and process them from there.

The second approach, which I was forced into solving because of a much higher volume of workbooks - like 200+ went like this:

- One has to trap the error twice, it seems.
- When you read the worksheet, there may be an error. That needs to be dealt with first.
- then, further processing like type conversions of the sort, text to int, causes error again. they can be dealt with now.

From my point of view, and I might not be describing this very well, trying to read a excel book, do some manipulations on it, and then mop up the errors at the end is not going to work. At every step of the glorious PowerQuery macro, you have to deal with errors as they occur.

That's the best way I could find out to get through it.

Comment: For the multiple errors question: If you add rows to a table or list, some values can add errors without breaking the full script. -- Other functions like `Web.Contents` or `Table.Sort...` can error at the query level. Those are usually fatal unless you catch them. -- Sometimes the UI will add multiple steps in one go. Like if you want to read a text file, sometimes you want `file.contents` and not the automatic convert from csv function. That indirection can sometimes give confusing errors  -- It's hard to give a solution without sample data

Comment: One line I noticed was `try #"Sorted Rows1" catch (e) => "Sorted Rows1"` . That says if Stuff is an error, return the error. You might have meant an earlier step.

Answer (score 0):

Data seems to load fine into powerquery with NA, #Ref and other errors in the source data. The issue would then be using those columns in additional steps

[image]

Why don't you edit your question to post the code you are using?

Comment: Maybe the problem is how I do "the load". In my query I have a table that uses a parameter to do a fetch, as an added column, 

That is different to just loading the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think he's describing a query-level exception, because he said he can't use "remove errors". Here's an example using `catch`.

If you want to catch one of those, you can use `try catch`. On the catch, either return the step that you would fallback to, or, return `[e]` if you want the error.

### Basic Catching

[image]

Or `[e]Message` if you want errors to return the exception as `type text`

```
let
    Source = Table.FromList({"a".."f"}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(),
        type table[ Name = text ], null, ExtraValues.Error),

    RemoveInvalidColumn = Table.RemoveColumns( Source, 
        {"Missing Col"}, MissingField.Error),
        
    FinalTable = 
        try RemoveInvalidColumn
        catch (e) => Source
in
    FinalTable
```

or edit the last step

```
FinalTable = 
    try RemoveInvalidColumn
    catch (e) => Source
```

### Circular references

Circular references means you're referencing a step earlier in the query, creating an infinite loop. Or, referencing the **query name** itself.

Are you using `#shared` or `#section` ?

### More Error Context

Here's one way to view additional error information, when you have a list of queries that some may fail. Using this query [github/Using Error Columns without losing column data-types.pq](https://github.com/ninmonkey/ninMonkQuery-examples/blob/96fd33ab255ceeccacc6f67048c9d2377ed6e21f/errorHandling/pq/Using%20Error%20Columns%20without%20losing%20column%20data-types.pq)

[image]

```
let
    // mixed data where some will fail for different reasons
    Source = Table.FromList(
        {
            "a", 20.3, "100", 39,
            DateTime.LocalNow(),
            TextEncoding.Utf8,
            #duration(1,2,3,4),                
            Binary.FromList({244})                
        }, Splitter.SplitByNothing(),
        type table[ RawValue = any ], null, ExtraValues.Error),

    // the column is type number, so we can't have it return errors as text 
    // you could incude metadata on it, which works even for null values
    // or create an error column
    CoerceNumber = Table.AddColumn(
        Source, "CoerceNumber",
        (row) =>
            try 
                Number.From( row[RawValue], "en-us" )
            catch (e) =>
                null meta [ ErrorInfo = e ],
                
        Number.Type
    ),

    Str = [ 
        NL = "#(cr,lf)",
        Quote = """"
    ],

    // take an error record and render it as a string with lines for spacing
    RenderError = (source as nullable record, optional options as nullable record) as text => [
        render = Text.Format( template, args, "en-us"),
        template = "Reason: #[Reason]#[NL]Message: #[FormattedText]#[NL]Detail: #[Detail]",
        args = [
            FormattedText = Text.Format( 
                source[Message.Format]?     ?? "",
                source[Message.Parameters]? ?? {},
                options[Culture]? ?? "en-us"
            ),
            Reason = source[Reason], 
            Detail = source[Detail],
            NL = Str[NL]
        ]
    ][render],

    // this column has an exception that you can expand to columns
    // you could have it return an empty record instead of a null value
    // I used null because then it's easy to know whether there's no information nested
    ErrorColumn = Table.AddColumn(
        CoerceNumber,
        "Error Info", 
        (row) =>
            let 
                item = Value.Metadata( row[CoerceNumber] ),
                errorInfo = item[ErrorInfo]? ?? null
            in 
                errorInfo,
        Record.Type
    ),
            
    // this column is purely text
    ShowRenderError = Table.AddColumn(
            ErrorColumn,
            "Show Error", 
            (row) =>                
                let
                    item = Value.Metadata( row[CoerceNumber] ),
                    errorInfo = item[ErrorInfo]?
                in 
                    if errorInfo = null then "" else RenderError( errorInfo ),                
            Text.Type
        )
in
    ShowRenderError
```

Comment: So one way I can expose the error very quickly, is to sort on the column. The sort bombs, and causes the error to reveal itself. 

So, as per your advice, try sort, and return the sorted table, or the error. 

But the "try to sort" interrupts the code ... so I can't get that far.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Added screenshot to the question

Comment: If I had the option, I would take the source data and export to CSV before doing all this manipulation... that would drop the root cause error in the source data ...